# Special relativity v.s. "homogeneous time" within an inertial reference frame

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, time-dilation

I am asking a conceptual question.

As we learned from classical mechanics, say Lagrangian formulation, as stated in Chap 7.9 of Classical Dynamics book by Thornton-Marion (5th Ed) p.260:

> in our previous arguments, that time is homogeneous within an inertial reference frame.

So, we have **"homogeneous time"** within an inertial reference frame.

My conceptual question is that how do we formulate a relativistic classical mechanics, say Lagrangian formulation, such that the we have "homogeneous time" within an inertial reference frame, but that there are

> **time dilations and time contractions effects** within special relativity classical mechanics?

In fact people have a successful Lagrangian formulation on the special relativity classical mechanics. But how does this work out conceptually? with this seemly dilemma:

> **"homogeneous time"** v.s. **time dilations and time contractions effects**  ?

p.s. I thought "Homogeneity" in time means the same "Homogeneity" as in fluid or the phase space. "Homogeneity" fluid means the fluid is non-contractible and non-compressible. But then I thought *"Homogeneity" in time means the time is non-contractible and non-compressible.*

Answer (score 1):

["Homogeneity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneity_(physics)#Translation_invariance) in time means being invariant under time translations.

Special relativity is invariant under the Poincaré group, and so in particular time translations.